# MVC ActionLink Error: Cannot convert from int to string

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, html.actionlink

I'm trying to pass the value that is displayed as action link to the controller as a parameter as below.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Convert.ToInt32(@row["SerialNo"]), GetPrvsIODtls, Home, new {SerialNo = row["SerialNo"]}, null)
```

But while Execution I get the error exception saying

> "CS1503: Argument2:cannot convert from int to string".